# Can someone explain this weird String things in GWT?

Tags: java, string, gwt, textbox

I used `String s="";`, `List<String>` etc in my Gwt projects & i had no error message what so ever.

However, when i used `String str=myTextBox.getText();` then eclipse gave an error saying that "Can not Cast from java.lang.String to String. So I changed to `java.lang.String str=myTextBox.getText();` then error was disappeared.

Question: what r the differences between String in `String s="";`, `List<String>` & String in `java.lang.String str=myTextBox.getText();` in my project?

So Gwt uses different String from core Java String?

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: String s=";   ??? is it valid ?

Comment: Do you have a class called `String` in the same package, or `import`ed?

Comment: No, i've never imported any package.String;

Answer (score 0):

GWT supports most of the core Java language syntax and semantics, but there are a few differences you will want to be aware of.
try check this https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility